# iOS - 1 view with 11 buttons linked to 1 switch. Switch only reacts to button 1-10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, switch-statement

I have an iOS app with a storyboard containing a viewcontroller with scrollview, containing a view with 11 buttons, lined up next to each other on a horizontal line. 
Each button is 210 x 80, and are linked to a method in the viewcontroller class. Inside this action method is a switch with a case of the sender.tag. Each button has a tag, the first being 1 and the last being 11. The switch reacts to all the buttons up to and including 10. All buttons over 10 aren't being recognised. I've even logged before the switch, and can see that if I add 15 buttons, all buttons after 10 don't even fire off the method. I've previously added the buttons programmatically, with the exact same result, which is weird, because the buttons are visible, and the scrollview acts like it should.
Have I stumbled across a limitation in the OS?
I'm only asking because there doesn't seem to be any logic to this whatsoever.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive they are linked in IB? When you click the 11th button, does the method get called? Try putting an NSLog outside the switch statement.

Comment: When you added them programmatically did you make sure to set the tags/action via `[UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvent:]` ?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure they are connected in the IB, as they're all connected the same way, and 1-10 functions. As I said I've logged before the switch and number 11+ button doesn't even fire the action.

As for commenter #2, I did make sure to set the action.
UIButton *u = [[UIButton alloc]init];
//            [u setImage:k forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [u setTag:pos];
           [u addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(ads:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            u.frame = CGRectMake(pos*210, 0, 210 , 80);
            [_adsView addSubview:u];

Comment: Maybe silly but are you sure you used correct `break` statement in your switch/case code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters suggested use the IB to check whether you are actually linked correctly.

- You may not have actually set the property correctly
- You might have duplicates somewhere where one item is sharing the same output in the IB
- It seems like you have a simple form, perhaps you could re-create it from scratch and try to duplicate?

Comment: None of the other things worked, so I recreated it like you said, deleted the one from the old project and inserted the new, and now it works. I still have no idea what caused it, but I'm just happy it works as it should now. Thank you for the help, you've saved me quite the headache.

Comment: Sometimes starting anew is the easiest

Comment: Sometimes this is the clearest solution. Especially when working with ib